# MySQL: Trigger with multiple if statements

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a MySQL trigger that conditionally (using IF statements) updates two columns with a random value from one of three columns from another table. When I change one of the two conditional values, both random columns get updated when it should only be one. Any help would be great!

DB fiddle to help explain the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2ad0a292678fb5ed39f6bc3e9c8ef11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add condition if new value is not equal to old value:

```sql
 IF (NEW.selection2 <> OLD.selection2 AND NEW.selection2 = 'fruits') THEN
    SET NEW.selection2_random = ( SELECT fruits
      FROM lists
      ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 );
 END IF;
```

While in BEFORE UPDATE trigger the NEW row references all the values before update, which means that for those columns not mentioned in UPDATE SET clause the NEW row will contain old values.